# ReactJS : How to import ES6 custom class ?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a class named Api.

**Api.jsx**

```
import axios from 'axios'
class Api {
    constructor(){
        this.base_url = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL
    }
    get = (url,params) => {
        return axios.get({
            url:`${url}`,
            base_url:`${this.base_url}`,
            params:params
        })
    }
}   

export default Api
```

How should i import this from a different file.
I am trying to make a generic api module.

Comment: I am getting this error 

TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__util_Api__.a.get is not a function

Please help !

Comment: How are you calling Api? How are you instantiating `Api Class`? Post the other file where you got the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can import the `Api` class in another file like this:

```
import Api from "../location/of/file/api.js";

const api = new Api();

api.get("/api/url", { param1: "foobar" }).then( response => {
   // ...
} );
```